# Is possible to reuse CSS auto-completion for values outside curly brackets?

Tags: css, monaco-editor

I'm working on a single monaco input for CSS values (`hsla(...), 10em, initial, calc(12px +1vh)`), but, using the current CSS language for monaco, I get auto-completion of CSS values only inside curly brackets, is there a way to reuse it outside brackets.

I have this input built with monaco-editor:

[image]

When I start typing on it, for example `hs` I don't get the completion/suggestion for the CSS expression of `hsla(hue, saturation, lightness, alpha)`, same for `ini` to `initial`, or any CSS value/expression. Instead of that, I just get auto-completion for HTML elements, pseudo elements or whatever, but not for CSS values:

[image]

The only way to get autocompletion for CSS values/functions it's just when expression is inside a curly braces like this:

[image]

So, my question is: is possible to get completion/suggestion for CSS values/expressions/functions outside curly braces or properties names?

Thank you for your humble/kind answer!

Comment: Hi @connexo, how are you? thanks for your kindly response. I have edited my question to be more clear with context and images. Do you have experience with monaco-editor? Can you please re-open the question? Thanks!

Comment: I don't have the required privilege, but voted to reopen.

Comment: Please, let me asking again, because the question is originally tagged as monaco-editor, do you have any experience with monaco-editor? I just wondering :-)

Comment: No, I don't even know what it is.

Comment: I'm assuming that even someone who knows the editor would have had a hard time figuring out what you are asking, before you edited your post.

Comment: Regardless how the question looked before, it is now in a shape that allows to reopen it.

Comment: Many thanks @MikeLischke, I appreciate it.